# Function returned negative 1. Might be segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

So, I was coding a problem on lintcode (number 69). I decided to use dfs using a traditional array as a queue. However, it returned -1 at the commented line, which lintcode says is a segmentation fault with the given input. Here is my code.

```cpp
/**
 * Definition of TreeNode:
 * class TreeNode {
 * public:
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left, *right;
 *     TreeNode(int val) {
 *         this->val = val;
 *         this->left = this->right = NULL;
 *     }
 * }
 */

class Solution {
public:
    /**
     * @param root: A Tree
     * @return: Level order a list of lists of integer
     */
    vector<vector<int>> levelOrder(TreeNode * root) {
        vector<vector<int>> result;
        if(root){
            TreeNode* Q[21];
            int f(0),b(0);
            Q[++b]=root;
            while(f<b){
                result.push_back(vector<int>());
                for(int i=b-f;i>0;i--){
                    auto n=Q[f++];
                    result.back().push_back(n->val);//Error occured the third time running this line
                    if(n->left)Q[++b]=n->left;
                    if(n->right)Q[++b]=n->right;
                }
            }
        }
        return result; 
    }
};
```

The input was {1,2,3} as a sequence of TreeNode s.

Comment: This sounds like a good opportunity to learn to use a debugger ;)

Comment: As for the problem, with the little code you show there's no bounds checking or null-pointer checking. Are you sure that you will never go out of bounds of `Q`? Or that you will never encounter a null pointer? Or possibly have invalid pointers added in your tree?

Comment: And a general tip: Don't use syntax like `int f(0);` for initialization. Sooner or later that will lead to you encountering [the most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) where you declare a function and not defining and initializing a variable. Use either curly braces (as in `int f{0};`) or the "normal" copy-initialization (using `int f = 0;`).

Comment: What is the structure of the tree? Is it 1->2->3 or 2<-1->3?

Comment: Your code tries to access memory address `0x0`. The value of `n` after `auto n=Q[f++];` is `0`. Then you try to access `n->val` with `n` equal to `0`. That causes a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines are a likely culprit:

```
Q[++b]=root;
...
auto n=Q[f++];
```

In the first, you increase `b` *before* using the value as an index, so it's equivalent to

```
Q[1] = root;
```

In the second line, when you execute it the first time the value of `f` is zero and you increase the value *after* you use it as an index, so it's equivalent to

```
auto n = Q[0];
```

Now, you haven't initialized `Q[0]`, so you will get an indeterminate value and have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to use the same sequence for both increases, either pre- or post-increase. I suggest post-increase to fully use the array (remember that array indexes are zero-based).